# Passing a value to page which comes after 2 redirects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on an application where users can post different kind of requirements. And each requirement is tied with a user. For posting a requirement, users are first redirected to a page("/select_requirement_type"). And on that page, user selects the type of requirement he wants and then he is redirected to the respective form. I basically use current_user.id to link it with a user.

Now also i have an admin user who can post requirements on behalf of other users. So the flow is still kind of the same. I list users on a page("/manage/users") and there the admin selects a user for which he want to post the requirement for and the page redirects to ("/select_requirement_type") and then the page redirects to the form. In the form instead of current_user.id I have to add the selected_user.id.

There are 2 redirects through which I have to pass the selected_user's id, how can accomplish this. And this cannot be passed as params along the url.
Im stuck with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Save the param to their session before the first redirect.